# Why console drops undefined instead of value of input, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I'm learnig React and I've got an problem with e.target.value, it returns undefined in the console.
Code below:

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {

    showMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.showMessage}>
            <input placeholder="name" name='name'/>
            <input placeholder="name" name='surName'/>
            <button type="submit">
                Wyświetl mnie!
            </button>
        </form>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(

    < Wrapper />,

    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: don't know much about react but a form don't only have one target and one value you should get the value of a more "primitive" element like an input

Answer (score 0):

```
showMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);

        console.log(formData.get('name'));
        console.log(formData.get('surName'));
    }
```

Comment: An explanation of *why* is often just as helpful (or more) than the *how*. Consider updating your answer with a description.

Answer (score -1):

Form elements (which is what `e.target` would be in this situation) don't have a `value`. I assume you would actually want to get the value from one of the inputs